# When to randomize auth code/state in oauth2?

Tags: go, oauth-2.0

According to the docs at https://www.godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2#Config.AuthCodeURL

> ...State is a token to protect the user from CSRF attacks. You must always provide a non-zero string...

and at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.12

> ...any request sent to the redirection URI endpoint to include a value that binds the request...

Yet this is specifically at the part in the flow when there is no session data, i.e. the user has not logged in and the auth code is only generated upon showing the anonymous page.

How then can this value be randomized and compared upon callback? Is it a static value randomized per server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> state
>
> RECOMMENDED.  An opaque value used by the client to maintain
> state between the request and callback.  The authorization
> server includes this value when redirecting the user-agent back
> to the client.  The parameter SHOULD be used for preventing
> cross-site request forgery as described in Section 10.12.

> [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)

You use `state` to identify that the callback from the authorization server matches the request sent. If there wasn't `state` a attacker could just call your callback url with a random access token that you didn't request. With `state` you know that the called callback is in response to the request you made.

So you randomize `state` per request that you sent and track it until you receive the matching callback. It can be anything you want as long as it can't be guessed.

A simple approach would be leveraging `rand.Reader` and base64 encoding the result:

```
func state(n int) (string, error) {
    data := make([]byte, n)
    if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, data); err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(data), nil
}
```

Comment: thing I'm confused about though is the "track it until..." part. Assuming that there could be multiple simultaneous requests, can't really set it as a global variable. Are you suggesting to add/delete from database rows or something?

Comment: You could use a `map[string]user.Identifier` where for each request you store your state along with the user identifier: `m[state] = userId`. When a callback arrives, look up the user identifier in your map and associate the received access token with it. Afterwards delete the key from the map. You will probably want to use some form of expiring cache to delete states that haven't been callbacked in a while.

Comment: got it - so yeah, same idea as db but doesn't need to be ironclad, like memcached?

Comment: memcached, redis, etc. Or if the callback always goes to the same instance that the request was made from, you can even do that in memory in go.

Comment: appengine, so memcache it is! :)

Comment: Don't forget to expire stale states after some time. Something like 5 min should be more than enough.